# Vuex ORM best practice for defining and mutating additional state

Tags: vuex, vuex-orm

I wan't to extend a vuex-orm model with a state like described in the documentation:
https://vuex-orm.org/guide/digging-deeper/vuex-module.html#defining-state

What ist the best way to mutate the state defined in the model? By defining a static function? I couldn't figure out how to use actions and mutations inside the model?

Here is my approach:

```js
import { Model } from '@vuex-orm/core'

export default class Todo extends Model {
  static entity = 'todos'

  static state ()  {
    return {
      selected_id: null
    }
  }

  static fields () {
    return {
      id: this.attr(null),
      title: this.string(''),
    }
  }

  static updateSelectedTodo (selected_id) {
    Todo.commit((state) => {
      state.selected_id = selected_id
    })
  }
}
```

And inside a component i have a method, which triggers the static todo method like this:

```js
methods: {
  updateSelectedTodo (selected_id) {
    Todo.updateSelectedTodo(selected_id);
  },
}
```

But this is no longer felt the vuex away.
Or is it a better approach to define a vuex module and pass it to it, as described here: https://vuex-orm.org/guide/digging-deeper/vuex-module.html#defining-modules

But this approach would split the state and mutation definitions in a seperate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static states defined on models still require a considerable amount of verbosity beyond generic mutation, and in direct reflection of your comment *"this is no longer felt the vuex way"*, you may be better off breaking this sort of logic into its own module to keep some form of Vuex consistency.

You don't necessarily have to put your module in a separate file, this is a matter of opinion. You can declare and export your module in the same file:

```js
export default class Todo extends Model {
  static entity = 'todos'

  static fields () { ... }
}

export const todos = {
  state: {
    selected_id: null
  },
  mutations: {
    updateSelected: (state, selected_id) => {
      state.selected_id = selected_id
    }
  },
  getters: {
    selected: (state) => state.selected_id
  }
}
```

And import it when registering to the store:

```js
import Todo, { todos } from '...'

database.register(Todo, todos)
```

Regardless, you will still need to invoke these mutations as you would generally with Vuex modules, with the exception you'll be invoking directly on the related model:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    selectedTodo: {
      get: () => Todo.getters('selected'),
      set: (selected_id) => Todo.commit('updateSelected', selected_id)
    }
  }
}
```